# jQuery if one statement is true and the other is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have a jQuery script that see's if .shipping has a descendant with a class of .sp-methods, and if it's true it will scroll down to the bottom of the page.

**Current Working jQuery**

```
if ($('.shipping .sp-methods').length > 0) {
        $('.shipping').show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
    },
    1400,
        "easeOutQuint");
}
```

Although what I want is the script to only run if that if that is true AND the element with an ID #shopping-cart does NOT contain the text "shipping" in it or any of its descendants. Just the text inside of something like this Shipping, not Shipping as a class or anything. Can contains do this?

I've tried this with no luck

**Broken jQuery**

```
if ($('.shipping .sp-methods').length > 0 && ! $("#shopping-cart:contains('shipping')")) {
    $('.shipping').show();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
    },
    1400,
        "easeOutQuint");
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I do that, no matter if the element has 'shipping' somewhere inside of it or not it scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the second condition follow the pattern of your first.
So try checking the length of the second:

EDIT: Looks like you also missed a single quote for `'shipping'`, updated the answer with it inserted.

```
if ($('.shipping .sp-methods').length > 0 && $("#shopping-cart:contains('shipping')").length <= 0) {
  $('.shipping').show();
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
  },
  1400,
      "easeOutQuint");
}
```

Comment: I realized the first line of the if statement doesn't have a closing quote around 'shipping', but with your above code and the ' fixed (my bad), it scrolls down to the bottom even if the element contains the text shipping somewhere in it.

Comment: @Xander then debug by outputting the array `$("#shopping-cart:contains('shipping')")` inside of the if statement. See why the condition isn't triggering.

Comment: This solution worked once I figured something out... I'm a big dummy and the #shopping-cart contains the word 'Shipping' and not 'shipping'. D'oh! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$("somethingNonExistent")` is `[]` (an empty array). You need to check its length in order to know if the search for your selector was successful.